# How to show columns of a comma delimitted file

Tags: linux

Guys how to show say for example columns 1,2 and 5 of a comma delimited file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cut` for simple comma delimited files:

```
cut -d, -f1,2,5 FILE
```

If the delimiter can be quoted, I would use Perl and its [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV).